# macOS Core Data – are toOne new records automatically assigned to the toMany Object the moment they are created?

Tags: macos, core-data, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I have two core data entities: `Category` and `Music`.

`Category` has a `toMany` relationship.
`Music` has a `toOne` relationship.

Each entity display their values on separate tables.
Tables are populated by independent `NSArrayControllers`.

I select a category on its table.

I create a new `Music` by this line on the code on `MusicArrayController`:

```
let newAttribute = self.newObject() as! Music
newAttribute.label = "New Music"
self.addObject(newAttribute)
```

If after that, that I check the last category I have selected, I see this new object is already in the category's toMany `NSSet`.

Example:

1. I select Rock and Roll in the category table.
2. Table 2 show the musics under that category.
3. I add a new music.
4. The Rock and Roll category has already that new music listed on its `toMany` `NSSet`.

I have not added any code to do that assignment.

Is this Core Data normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array controller shows and manages the `Music` objects of the `Category`. When a `Music` object is added with `self.addObject(newAttribute)` then the array controller adds the `Music` object to the relationship. This is normal `NSArrayController` behaviour, with and without Core Data.

Comment: fantastic. I never knew that. Thanks. It is amazing how it knows which category to add the object relationship, because I have two array controllers.